# Mathematical formalism to include wave and particle perspectives of light

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, quantum-electrodynamics

Does the exist any mathematical formalism (model) describing the behavior of light and incorporating its particle character (divisibility, quantization) and wave character? (i.e. quantized wave model)

Comment: It's called "quantum field theory".

Comment: In particular for photons it's quantum electrodynamics.