# Mathematical model that allows the existence of an infinite number of smallest, but different particles

Tags: particle-physics

Does there exist a mathematical formalism (model) in particle physics that assumes the existence of an infinite number of different, yet smallest particles (building blocks)?

Comment: Why should there? The Standard Model does fine with about a handful, and an infinity of particles would mean an infinity of parameters to tweak (the masses, at least). Such a model has no predictive power. [Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127279/]

Comment: If this potential lack of predictive power means to you an overfitting situation due to a number of parameters, then it is not the case, since some variables can be later on (in a real prediction case, e.g. for an experiment) reduced using dimensionality reduction. By asking this question, I want to learn wheather there already exists such a model. For specifically, do any experiments encourage us to introduce such a model?

Comment: Nothing stops you from introducing countably many fields into a QFT. It's just overkill, as the SM shows. I really don't get what the value of this question is supposed to be, since there is nothing in the real world even *slightly* indicating that there may be infinitely many types of particles.

Comment: ACuriousMind, you actually answered my question perfectly. If all the experiments confirm the SM and it is highly unlikely that we will continue finding building blocks of quarks, etc., then I fully agree with your claim here.

Comment: It's a little bit strange that in the [SM](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) photons are counted as a particle in the same meaning as quarks . Quarks are well defined with their energy, they are unicque. Photons exist in varying energies. Why it isn't imaginable that photons are composed from more elementary particles? Perhaps in the magnitude of Planck comstant?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler *"Quarks are well defined with their energy,"* No they are not. They come in a range of energies (all energies if you include the virtual contribution). What is defined (sort of) is their masses, and the mass of a photon is also defined (it happens to be zero).

Comment: @dmckee are you not agree with "energy" and it should read "Quarks are well defined with their energies"?
Until your comment I thought that quarks were clearly defined. Protons, neutrons and other baryons are composed particles from a exact defined number of quarks. And a photon with energy higher than 1.022 MeV can decay in a electron-positron-pair (or some other pairs). All this processes are well defined.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler The points are (1) that it is the *mass* that is well defined (an intrinsic property of the particle) not the energy (which depends on external factors) and (2) that the mass of the photon is also well defined. Photons are different from quarks because they have different quantum numbers not because one is more entitled to the mantle of "particle" than the other.

Comment: @dmckee No doubt quarks and photons are different kind of materia.
What does I mean with the range of energies of photons (from terahertz/infrared to gamma) is that you can get pair production from photons of varying energies. There is no THE photon. But there is THE up-quark. Explaine to me please why it is not thinkable, or better why it is impossible that photons are composed from smaller particles?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler No (on-shell) photon ever spontaneously pair produces: it requires help from the environment (in a typical discussion this is a "spectator nucleus") and sufficiently high-energy quarks have similar processes. Again, neither photon nor quarks have a fixed energy and they both have fixed mass.

Comment: See my elaboration about [Are photons composed particles](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler) as well as [Complex one-dimensional structures of space](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler) available in English and German