# Does quark have fixed energy?

Tags: quarks, elementary-particles

Does a quark, for example a up-quark has a fixed energy? The [standard model](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg) gives well defined masses in MeV which is energy too.

Comment: Presumably related to the comments here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127283/

Comment: The masses are in MeV since you can use $E = mc^2$ to translate them to mass.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: MeV and the derivation E=mc2 can be used for quarks to explain their mass. Not so for photons. On the over side photons have a big range of energy and momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (on-shell) quark has fixed *mass*. It's energy depens on the frame of reference you use for asking the question.

Mass is a Lorentz scalar (i.e. is invariant). Energy is one component of the energy-momentum four-vector and is *not* invariant.